# Pausing a BackgroundWorker from another method

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a program that is continuously running.

When I start the program, I have a BackgroundWorker (InitialStart.cs):

```
    BackgroundWorker recordingSyncWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    recordingSyncWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(RecordingSyncCheck);
    recordingSyncWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
    recordingSyncWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    recordingSyncWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    void RecordingSyncCheck(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        cHandler ch = new cHandler();
        Timer theTimer;
        int seconds = 1;
        if (taskSeconds != null && taskSeconds != "")
            seconds = Convert.ToInt32(taskSeconds);
        int milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
        theTimer = new Timer(10000);
        theTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ch.SyncMethod);
        theTimer.Interval = milliseconds;
        theTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

And I have two methods in another class (cHandler.cs):

```
    SyncMethod(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // random code
    }
    private string SDCardCheck(object whatever)
    {
        //more code
    }
```

SDCardCheck gets called thru WCF, so it's like there is another instance of cHandler.cs running.  Is there a way for me to pause the BackgroundWorker when I call SDCardCheck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a BackgroundWorker just to start a timer.  Starting a timer is not a long running operation; it can be done directly from the UI thread.

Your other method can disable the timer to stop it from firing, and then enable it again to allow it to continue firing, in order to effectively pause its execution.

Comment: Worth noting that, to do that, the `Timer` needs to have a wider scope than just the method.

Comment: I disabled the BackgroundWorker, and just ran it directly from the UI thread.  Initial tests seem good.  I think the BackgroundWorker was a remnant from previous version, as the Syncing method is much more streamlined.